# LocateOnScreen is not enough accurate

Tags: python, image-recognition, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui to locate images on my screen.
I used these 2 images :

[image]

[image]

My problem is that, even with confidence at 1, pyautogui can't make a difference betweens these two images.

Is there any way to improve accuracy other than using 1 as confidence parameter?

Maybe another library or api would have better performance?

I am using the locateOnScreen method.

Comment: maybe use images with more pixels around text - so they will be more different.

Comment: This is not possible since there are exactly the same pixels around these buttons.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would add image with full screen which has buttons. Maybe you will have to use `locateOnScreen` to locate buttons and later check also colors in this regions - `pixelMatchesColor()` - and this may need more work. As I remember `locateOnScreen` may convert images to grayscale before searching. Or check in documentation if function can compare in colors.

Comment: you may also use `locateAllOnScreen()` to get all locations and later search by `pixelMatchesColor()`. And if button can be only in some region then you could crop screenshot before searching. With screenshot (and example code) we could test some ideas.

Comment: @furas i didn't see about pixelMatchesColor, this is smart. Thanks